# Объясните на пальцах о процессах и кластерах Node.js

Tags: node.js, pm2

Не до конца понимаю как запускаются приложения на Node.

Если скажем запустить app1.js и app2.js к примеру через какой-нибудь process manager (pm2 или strongloop PM) ну или просто в консоли node app1.js и node app2.js что получается? Это будут создаваться 2 отдельных процесса ноды в ОС, где один процесс работает с app1, а второй процесс с app2? Или же это процессы app1 и app2 внутри самой ноды?

И по кластеризации к примеру в тех же самых pm2 или strongloop PM, в документации написано что типа на каждое ядро вешается по одному процессу ноды в ОС. 
Т.е. я не могу понять что же такое процесс и что такое кластер? Это все на уровне ОС размножается или же что-то на уровне ноды?

Можете как-то разъяснить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выполняя в консоли node app1.js вы запускаете экземпляр программы node с передачей в качестве аргумента пути файла приложения. Да, каждый такой вызов порождает процесс nodejs. Кластер это несколько процессов nodejs, внутри ноды ничего не размножается.